# Distance from curve to plane

Tags: geometry

What is the function which defines the distance from the plane to the curve as a function of the angle. Currently shows the distance for a circle inclined $15^\circ$ to the plane. $10.729^\circ$ @ $45^\circ$. Ultimately I need to get the distance from the curve to the plane at a given angle, but before I can do a projection, I need the angle itself...

Updated the image. Realized $45^\circ$ rotation should be on the plane rather than on the circle.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ denote the distance along the common axis of plane and curve. Let $b$ denote the length perpendicular to that axis but within the plane. Let $c$ denote the distance from the origin to the point on the plane nearest to the point on the curve. And let $d$ denote the perpendicular distance between point on the curve and plane. Then you know

$$\frac ba=\tan45° \qquad \frac db=\tan15° \qquad a^2+b^2=c^2$$

From this you want to compute

$$\frac{d}{c}=\tan x$$

Since you only talk about angles, you can choose your unit of length any way you want. So let's choose $c=1$. Then you have

$$a=\cos45° \qquad b=\sin45° \qquad d=\sin45°\,\tan15°$$

Now you can solve

$$x = \arctan\left(\sin45°\,\tan15°\right)\approx10.7285831216°$$